# iOS: Passing javascript variable from child to parent window

Tags: javascript, ios

When opening a url with target set to _blank, it's possible to pass variables from the child window to the parent window using the parent/opener property. This works in a desktop browser but on iOS (using Chrome on iPad) the parent/opener is null and not accessible.

How can this be achieved on iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to store the variable you need passed between the two windows. I doubt that you could do anything else but pass variables as you can only have one "tab" open at a time in iOS.

Alternatively, you could use PHP and pass the variable as a GET in the url `http://myurl.com/page.php?myvar=blah` and retrieve it that way.

Comment: Thanks! localStorage could be a solution.